# .htaccess protect download private files from user's directory using php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpcookie

My php script create a user's directory to store private files and I need to keep it private except for the owner.

Basically my structure is like this:

```
- root/
- storage/
---- users/
----------user1/
---------------.htaccess
---------------images/
---------------tmp/
-------------------session-id-file
----------user2/
---------------.htaccess
---------------images/
---------------tmp/
-------------------session-id-file
```

This means when a new user register then a new user's directory is created in /storage/users:

`$dir = __DIR__ . "/storage/user/" . $user["id"];
    mkdir($dir);`

Then a new .htaccess is created inside:

```
 $myfile = fopen($file, "w") or die("Unable to create file!");
 $txt = "RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}        PHPSESSID=(\w+)\n
 **RewriteCond {CURRENT-DIRECTORY}/tmp/access-%1      -f \n**
 RewriteRule ^(.+)$  $1  [L]\n
 RewriteRule .+  /deny   [L]\n";
 fwrite($myfile, $txt);
 fclose($myfile);
```

The .htaccess appears as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}        PHPSESSID=(\w+)
RewriteCond {CURRENT-DIRECTORY}/tmp/access-%1      -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$  $1  [L]

RewriteRule .+  /deny   [L]
```

When user login  a new session-id-file is crerated in user's tmp directory:

`touch($dir . "/tmp/" . session_id());`

My question is: how detect {current directory}  where the htaccess  is located ? Basically how fix the wrong line in .htaccess:

```
        RewriteCond {CURRENT-DIRECTORYY}}/tmp/access-%1      -f \n
```

I have seen similar question but I'm not able to detect current directory based on directory created on fly.

A good option could be using just one .htaccess into /users directory instead of many .htaccess for each user as I did in my example.

Thanks for any suggestion :)

Comment: Do you want deny all access /storage/users? Do I understand it right?

Comment: Yes. Except for owner. I detect owner using session_id file and cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can change:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1 [L]
```

To:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Which means the same thing. `-` can be used to say don't make any change, just apply the flags.

For denying, you can do that properly using the `[F]` flag to return a 403 forbidden, instead of a 200 rewrite to `/deny`. Like so:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

If you still want the contents of `/deny` to be returned then add an `ErrorDocument` directive for 403 and point it to that page.

For writing to a file in PHP, you can just use `file_put_contents` instead of those three calls to `fopen`, `fwrite` and `fclose`. See [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

To answer your actual question, for the current directory, you can't get it directly from `RewriteCond` variables, but you can just write it in to the file when you generate it with PHP.

Here's an example of that with the other suggested changes:

```
$txt = "RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} PHPSESSID=(\w+)\n
RewriteCond $dir/tmp/access-%1 -f\n
RewriteRule ^ - [L]\n
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]\n";
file_put_contents($myfile, $txt) or die("Unable to create file!");
```

So it becomes, for example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} PHPSESSID=(\w+)
RewriteCond /root/storage/users/userid/tmp/access-%1 -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Comment: Thanks!  Good point!  I have another error because the condition: RewriteCond /httpdocs/storage/user/1/tmp/access-%1 -f is  NOT TRUE, but file exists. Hmmm I checked and value %1 is correct  (and the session file exists in path).

Comment: Perhaps double check that path? It's different to the path structure you specified above, perhaps you have a mistake in the path. `/user/1` instead of `/users/user1`.

Comment: Other than that, make sure that Apache has access to the path, and look at setting `LogLevel rewrite:trace3` (or a higher level of trace up to 8) in your main Apache config to see what's going wrong with the rules.

Comment: no, its correct. I verified it by FTP. ftp://ftp.*******.com//httpdocs/storage/user/11/tmp/4ie3ac4nlv4unl14uovnomb0r4 and used "/httpdocs/storage/user/11/tmp/%1" on htaccess. At same I verified htaccess got correct php session id.

Comment: So remove the `.htaccess` file and see if you can access files when it's not there, to make sure Apache has access. It may be just forbidden because Apache doesn't have access there. Then look at adding the logging I suggested in second comment above to see what's going wrong.

Comment: I can see the session id file on browser (removing httdpocs from path, which is the root directory on server). I tried add .txt but no happened.  Tomorrow I'll chck the apache config to see how is set LogLevel rewrite:trace3. Thanks a lot helping me :)

Comment: Thanks @SuperDuperApps! I fix it adding the predir to my path, having the whole path on my vhost:  /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/demo/storage/users/userid/tmp/access-%1 instead of home directory only. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear it. You're welcome :) Thanks for the update.